# how DC component is removed?

Tags: filter

Given these waveforms:

[image]

and the first difference system:

[image]

there are discontinuities at omega = 0 ,2pi, ...  I know that there is a DC component, but how is the DC component at omega=0 removed from the system?  Can anyone please help me?

Comment: and the system emphasized the higher frequecny (nearly omega =pi) to the lower frequency.. how the system is high pass filter;?

Comment: can a high pass filter remove the discontinous and DC from signal.. if yes then why there is discontiouse in the siganl given in figure...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try it.

A pure DC signal, for example would be:

\$x[n] = 1_{\mbox{for all n}}\$

Now try solving for \$y[n]\$ for any value of n. What is it?

Comment: i think it will be 0 for any value of n... because its costant at n =1...

Comment: @kortuk: as i know DC component at frequency omega =0 ..

Comment: @miss, a signal that is a constant for all n is a DC signal. If your output is perfectly 0 after the filter you have rejected the signal, right?

Comment: @kortuk : yes right ...

Comment: @kortuk: that mean in the above figure .. DC component is not there.. but how this system is high pass filter at nearly omega =pi ?

Comment: @kortuk: ahh i see.. since there exit a DC compoent at omega =0.. so after filtering ..the constant signal removed.. thats why its a high pass filter at omega = pi ... yes now its make sence to me

Comment: @kortuk: the point here is that still there are discountinous at omega =0,2pi...it should removed.. is't

Comment: if high pass filter can remove the DC component then can it remove also discountinous in signal.. as it have discontinous at omega = 0 and 2pi..

Comment: @miss, there are not any discontinuities.

Comment: @kotuk: no, phase have discontinuties at omega = 0 ,2pi..

Comment: @miss, phase graphs are from -180 degrees to +180 degrees, it is not a discontinuity, 181 degrees and -179 degrees are equal. This means that it has just gone from 180 to -180. This is not a discontinuity.

Comment: @kortuk: hmm but book mentioned that phase have discontinus at omega =0,+ve2pi and -ve2pi

Comment: book mentioned also that "the size of discontinous is pi. "

Comment: @miss, that is not a discontinuity I would fret over, but do you also notice that the signal is 0? If the signal is 0 the phase shift affects nothing.